# Filling between two plots up to some boundaries only

Tags: plotting, text, filling

Suppose I have plotted two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on the same plot. I would like to shade the area between the two curves only when $f(x) \geq g(x)$, but I cannot get the Filling command to do the job. Here is my code:

```
f[n_, d_] := (Sin[Pi/n] + (Sin[Pi/n]^2 + 4*n^2*d^2)^(1/2))/(2*n);R[n_, d_] := 1 - (d^2 + Cos[Pi/n]^2)^(1/2);Plot[{f[4, d], R[4, d]}, {d, 0, 0.2}, AxesLabel -> {d},  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",  Filling -> {1 -> {2}, R[4, d] > f[4, d]}]
```

The graph produces the shaded region everywhere between $f(4,d)$ and $R(4,d)$, but I only want the region between the two curves when $R(4,d) \geq f(4,d)$, or in other words, up untill $d \simeq 0.16$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the documentation of Filling please. That already explained everything.

Comment: I believe you want e.g. `Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, None}}}`

Comment: @Alex You're welcome.  A couple of notes: (1) If ever your question is marked as a duplicate but you still cannot find a solution to your problem you can edit the question to explain how your needs differ, and it will automatically be added to the Reopen Review Queue.  (2) You may find value in reading the **Related** questions linked in the sidebar to the right, or browsing the [tag:filling] tag directly.